# Filter Google Spreadsheet Array Formula

Tags: google-sheets, sorting

I have a spreadsheet with 2 columns. `B1` contains a custom function that returns an array that overflows to fill the column. I want to create a few filter views that each show all entries with 1 given value in column `B`, and sorts by column `A`. The original data can't be presorted. I can get the filter to show only the specified value from `B`, but once I try to sort by column `A`, it breaks and no longer shows the contents of `B`, except for `Loading...` in the cell the formula was placed in.

I saw some info on some `CONTINUE` function, which looked like it could fix my problem, but unfortunately that function was removed in the new Google Spreadsheets. Is there an alternative to `CONTINUE` in the new Google Spreadsheets or some other way I can do this?

Comment: Does the function in B1 use column A as the input?

Comment: Also, does the range which you sort include the cell with your custom function? Does this cell get moved to another position as a result?

Comment: Yes, yes, and yes, but I could easily move the function to display the header and sort only the cells that don't contain the function.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is caused by filtered view sorting the column that contains input to a function. It can be reproduced in the following minimal example:

```
+---+-------+---+
|   |   A   | B |
+---+-------+---+
| 1 | input | 1 |
| 2 | 5     |   |
| 3 | 4     |   |
+---+-------+---+
```

where B1 is the formula `=A2-A3`. Create a filtered view for cells A1:B3 and use it to sort column A in ascending order. The result: B1 will display #REF error

> The formula in cell A2 is referencing a range in the active filter that is not in the same row.

I can't really explain why this fails: my guess is that the logic of filtered view does not handle remapping cell references within the view.

But I can suggest an alternative approach: use `FILTER` and `SORT`, possibly putting results on different sheets for ease of sharing or reading.  For example,

```
=SORT(FILTER(A2:A15, B2:B15=5), 1, TRUE)
```

keeps only the entries from A with 5 in column B, and presents them in ascending order. This formula could appear in another column (C,...), or on a different sheet.