# Alternate colored lines in Google Sheets that respect filter views

Tags: google-sheets

Basically I want the zebra stripes effect for readability but all the methods I've found so far don't work when using filter views. Does anyone know a way or is this not possible?

Update: Using a Filter instead of Filter View helps (Thanks user 404) but it would be helpful if a proper solution could be found anyway

Comment: Filter or filter views? See [Color every other row in filter view](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/82397#82402)

Comment: If you are using filter views, then this is exactly like the other question.